# Why are threads not used much in emacs packages?

Tags: threading

Is there some drawback in their current implementation which makes using them less appealing?

Comment: They are very new, and probably not relevant to most libraries.  Is there a specific example of sufficiently-new code where you think threads should have been used, and weren't?

Comment: The question is: what does the current thread implementation provides which can not be done with async processes?

Comment: A couple of examples: (1) They can deal with operations which do not involve external processes at all.  (2) It might well be easier to adapt synchronous code to use threads than it would be to rewrite it using an asynchronous paradigm.

Comment: TIL: There are threads in Emacs. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.